# I run the 'npm start' command, but it takes HOURS to start the whole Web Project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

Currently our team is developing a web project using `NodeJS` with the combination of `React-Redux`. At the beginning of the development, the project starts fast,but as the increment of the project, it turns slower and slower. Until now, every time I run the '`npm start`' command,it takes nearly **1 hour** to start the whole project.In addition every time I changed my javascript code, it would take **nearly 2 minutes to recompile** the project. It is the first time that our company use 'React' and `Redux`. We don't know what happened or what to do with it. We put `nearly all the business-parameters` as `Global variables` of `Redux`. I tried changing the configuration of `devtool` in the `webpack.config.js` hoping for a faster starting, only resulting in `memory out of heap!` . Will this affect the operating efficiency of our project? Is it harmful to the System? What is the usual cause of this problem as I described? How can I fix it?
The following are our configuration files(webpack.config.js and package.json)

```
//webpack.config.js
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");
var glob = require('glob');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var entries = getEntry('src/Html/**/*.js', 'src/Html/');
entries['index'] = './src/app.js';
var config = {
devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: entries,
    output: {
        path: "dist",
        filename: "js/[name].js",
        chunkFilename: "js/[name].js"
    },
module: {
    loaders:[
        {
            test: require.resolve('jquery'),
            loader: 'expose?jQuery!expose?$'
         },
        {
            test: /\.js[x]?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react'
      },{
          test: /\.css$/, 
          loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' 
      },{
          test: /\.less/,
          loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader'
      }, {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
          loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192&name=img/[hash].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins:[
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
              warnings: false
             }
            }),
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: false,
            mangle: false
            }),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env': {NODE_ENV:  JSON.stringify("production")}
            }),
           new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
             $:"jquery",
             jQuery:"jquery",
             "window.jQuery":"jquery"
           })
         ],
         resolve: {
             alias: {
                 jquery: "jquery/src/jquery"
             }
         },
  babel:{
       plugins:[["import", [{ "libraryName": "antd", "style": "css" }]]]
  },
  externals: {
        jquery: 'window.$',
        artTemplate: 'window.template'
  },
  devServer: {
        contentBase: "./",                   // 
        colors: true,                            // 
        historyApiFallback: true,                //
        inline: true,                          // 
        port: 8205
  },

};

var pages = getEntry('src/Html/**/*.html', 'src/Html/');
var pagenames = Object.keys(pages);

config.plugins.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: './index.html',
    template: './src/index.html',
    inject: true,
    chunks: ['index'],
    hash: true,
    minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: false
    }
}));

pagenames.forEach(function (pagename) {
    var conf = {
        filename: './pages/' + pagename + '.html',
        template: pages[pagename],
        inject: 'body',
        minify: {
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: false
        }
    };
    if (pagename in config.entry) {
        conf.inject = true;
        conf.chunks = [pagename];
        conf.hash = true;
    }
    config.plugins.push(new HtmlWebpackPlugin(conf));
});
function getEntry(globPath, pathDir) {
    var files = glob.sync(globPath);
    var entries = {},
        entry, dirname, basename, pathname, extname;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        entry = files[i];
        dirname = path.dirname(entry);
        extname = path.extname(entry);
        basename = path.basename(entry, extname);
        pathname = path.join(dirname, basename);
        pathname = pathDir ? pathname.replace(new RegExp('^' + pathDir), '')     : pathname;
        entries[basename] = './' + entry;
    }
    return entries;
}

module.exports = config;
//=================================================================

//-------- package.json
{
  "private": true,
  "entry": {
    "index": "./src/index.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
  "redux-thunk":"2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "atool-build": "^0.9.0",
    "atool-test-mocha": "^0.1.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-import": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.9.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.11.6",
    "better-npm-run": "0.0.11",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "cssnano": "^3.7.4",
    "debug": "^2.2.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "eslint": "^3.8.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^12.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^2.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.4.1",
    "expect": "^1.20.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "pre-commit": "1.x",
    "redbox-react": "^1.2.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.22.0",
    "glob": "^7.0.6"
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "lint"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx src/",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline",
    "test": "atool-test-mocha ./**/__tests__/*-test.js",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --devtool eval --progress --colors --hot --    content-base build"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you have excessive entries for webpack. What hardware do you use? You may need a hardware upgrade.

Comment: To iterate faster, consider changing your `process.env` to `"development"`. Normally, you would use a different webpack config for your build script that specified your production-only optimisations. Leaving this on `production` at all times is going to mean long compile times. See [this](https://github.com/dmachat/angular-webpack-cookbook/wiki/Creating-a-dev-and-production-config) or [this](http://jonnyreeves.co.uk/2016/simple-webpack-prod-and-dev-config/) for more details on config splitting.

Comment: CPU : intel i5 2.8G hz 4 cores ,  RAM:8G, windows7 x64. I don't think it's caused by hardware, It must be the configuration problem.

Comment: I can't really help with your current configuration but I suggest you to create a whole new webpack setup and maybe use gulp for assets like css. You can disable the Uglify plugin in dev to.

Comment: We finally find that it is caused by the large amount of repeated loading in every service modules,but of couse this has some related reasons with the aging of my hardware.I will write down the resolution of this problem in a few days.

Comment: @ChasonLuis Solution? :)